# Didn't know how to get the current location and show nearby car services(workshops)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a google maps in one fragment in my app. How can I get the current location and show nearby car services?

```
package com.example.easyauto;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class HartaFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    View view;   // for the view
    GoogleMap map;   // for the GoogleMaps
    MapView mapView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_harta, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapsView);

                if(mapView != null){
                    mapView.onCreate(null);
                    mapView.onResume();
                    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

                }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        map = googleMap;  // show the maps ok 
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote for now. It all works fine. Do I need also to put tha map_fragment.xml here for more details? 
 I also added the meta-data for google maps and the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0',

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend to be more concise in your questions to be easier to answer for other people. You aren't quite asking a question, but asking for someone else to do it for you.
I would hardly recommend to follow some sort of [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-google-maps/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training) about google maps.

Answer (score -1):

As

> map.getMyLocation()

is depracated you can try this:

```
   public Location getLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            Location lastKnownLocationGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (lastKnownLocationGPS != null) {
                return lastKnownLocationGPS;
            } else {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And dont forget about permissions (runtime and in manifest).